# Can Python instance methods be automatically defined at __init__ time?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, instance-methods, python-class

I'm wondering if instance methods can be created automatically in Python when `__init__` is executed. Consider this code example where a class is defined to handle some audio file format metadata (exceptions handling and not relevant stuff omitted):

```
__tags__ = ['album', 'artist', 'date', 'genre', 'title', 'tracknumber']

class Tags():
    def __init__(self):
        for tag in __tags__:
            setattr(self, tag, None)

    def print(self):
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            if v:
                print('{}: {}'.format(k, str(v)))

    def get(self, *pa):
        ret = [getattr(k) for k in pa if k in __tags__]
        return ret if len(pa)>1 else ret[0]

    def set(self, **ka):
        for k, v in ka.items():
            if k in __tags__:
                setattr(self, k, str(v))
```

Now:

```
    mytags = Tags()
    mytags.set(album='The best of Ennio Morricone', artist='Various Artists')
    mytags.print()
    print()
    mytags.set(genre='Soundtrack', tracknumber=3)
    mytags.set(title='Secret Of The Sahara')
    mytags.print()
    print(mytags.album is mytags.get('album'))
```

prints:

```
album: The best of Ennio Morricone
artist: Various Artists

album: The best of Ennio Morricone
artist: Various Artists
genre: Soundtrack
title: Secret Of The Sahara
tracknumber: 3
True
```

Suppose now I want to add `get_<tag>/set_<tag>` methods for every single tag, i.e. `mytags.set_album(album)` or `title=mytags.get_title()`. Given that `mytags.set_album(album)` translates to `mytags.set({'album':album,})`, is there a pythonic way to automatically create these methods when the instance is created?
Stupid non-working example just to try to explain what I mean:

```
    class Tags():
        def __init__(self):
            for tag in __tags__:
                setattr(self, tag, None)
                setattr(self, 'set_'+tag<reference to passed in argument>,
                        <reference to the respective self.set() method>)
```

This would save a lot of typing and, above all, it wouldn't require any change should `__tags__` be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create functions and bind them to instances as instance methods, e.g.,

```
def __init__(...):
    tag = "album"
    def whatever_func(self, gettag=tag):
       return getattr(self, gettag)
    setattr(self, f"get_{tag}", whatever_func.__get__(self))
```

It's not pretty, though, right? I think you'd be better off defining a `__getattr__` to deal with any attribute access that is not defined; you should also define `__dir__` so that these dynamic attributes are tab-completable.